# Plotly in Jupyterlab: difference between show method and display (effect on plotly on_change)

Tags: plotly, jupyter-lab, plotly-python, yaxis

In JupyterLab, using Plotly, I have set up a callback to update the y-axis when zooming.

Please refer to the code below for a complete example.

The zoom function is connected to the layout using on_change.

The `yaxis` updates correctly when the figure is displayed using IPython's `display` or directly with `fig`. However, it stops working if the `figure.show()` method is used.

What is the issue with this method in this particular scenario? Why does on_change no longer work?

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 100, 1000)
y = 0.1* x * np.sin(2 * np.pi * 0.1 * x)

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': x, 'Value': y})
df = df.set_index('Time')

fig = go.FigureWidget()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['Value'], mode='lines')
)

fig.update_layout(
        xaxis={'rangeslider_visible': True}
)

# callback function to update yaxis min and max upon zoom
def zoom(layout, xrange):
    in_view = df.loc[fig.layout.xaxis.range[0]:fig.layout.xaxis.range[1]]
    fig.layout.yaxis.range = [in_view.Value.min(), in_view.Value.max()]
    
fig.layout.on_change(zoom, 'xaxis.range')

#fig            # on_change (zoom) works!
display(fig)    # on_change (zoom) works!
#fig.show()     # on_change (zoom) doesn't work
```

I am aware that `figure.show()` utilizes the renderers framework, but I am unable to understand its functionality in this "on_change" scenario.

Could someone shed some light on this or direct me to the appropriate documentation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also ran into this problem where using the `show()` method prevented the `on_change` handler from working.

1. The use of `fig.show()` actually calls the `plotly.io.show()` method, which re-renders the object itself based on the specified renderer. However, the `on_change` event handler is a standalone event module, and is not part of the Figure's property. Therefore, it will not be included when plotly.io re-renders it, and the `fig.show()` method won't carry `on_change()` settings. On the other hand, executing `fig/display(fig)` just displays the object in JupyterLab/Notebook, without re-rendering, so there is no issue.
2. If you are using `show()` to pass the config parameter, that is likely where the problem is. The `fig.show(config=config)` method actually sets the figure's private attribute `_config`, which inherits from the parent class `BaseFigure`, and the only API interface to modify it is through the `show()` method. Therefore, if you want to make `on_change` work and set config at the same time, use `fig.__setattr__('_config', config)` to set fig's config, such as `scrollZoom = True`.

Btw, it's a good idea to use `fig.__getattributer__('_config')` to get the original `_config` value first, and then merge it with the new value you want to assign.

```
...

# set callback
fig.layout.on_change(zoom, 'xaxis.range')

# prepare mouse wheel zoom for example
_config = dict(scrollZoom=True)

# get original _config attribute and merge with yours
_config = fig.__getattribute__('_config') | _config
fig.__setattr__('_config', _config)

# now you have both scrollZoom config and on_change zoom
# callback work together, and don't use fig.show()
fig
```

It's not the official way, but it's an acceptable practice until plotly solves the `show()` issue.